# Send HTML content via SendGrid v3

Tags: go, sendgrid, email, sendgrid-api-v3

I use GO and I try send mail via sendgrid API v3(https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go Without Mail Helper Class). But when i use this code:

```
"content": [
    {
      "type": "text/html", 
      "value": "<html><head></head><body>Hello You link <a href="http://example.com/reschedule?id=12334">Click</a></body></html>"
    }
  ],
```

i get error:

> 400 {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}

But this code works correctly:

```
"content": [
    {
      "type": "text/html", 
      "value": "<html><head></head><body>Hello!</body></html>"
    }
  ],
```

I think problem in special characters, but how i can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: the problem is probably the `"` inside your `value`, you have to put `&quot;`

Answer (score 5):

Need do this:

```
<div class=\"ad_box\"><img class=\"banner\" src=\"some_ad.png\" alt=\"\" \/>

Example
    "content": [
        {
          "type": "text/html", 
          "value": "<html><head></head><body>Hello You link <a href=\"http://example.com/reschedule?id=12334\">Click</a></body></html>"
        }
      ],
```

Comment: yeah, you need to escape your in-html quotes.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem, same escapes special characters, what solved was to use the official client to go and its helpers.

Sample code:

```
from := mail.NewEmail("from", "from@mail.com")
to := mail.NewEmail("to", "to@mail.com")
content := mail.NewContent("text/html", contentHtml)

email := mail.NewV3MailInit(from, "Sample about sendgrid client", to, content)

personalization := mail.NewPersonalization()
personalization.AddTos(to)
email.AddPersonalizations(personalization)

client := sendgrid.NewSendClient(os.Getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
response, err = client.Send(email)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Cannot send the email: %v", err)
}

if response.StatusCode != 202 {
    return fmt.Errorf("Cannot send the email: %s", response.Body)
}
```

[sendgrid-go](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go)

[helpers sample](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-go/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.go)